# Unable to add network printer using python

Tags: python-2.7, printing

I am very new to python and trying to execute printer installation using python but it doesn't work. If I execute the same using cmd, it works.

```
import os
os.system("rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n \\print-kunnu.com\FollowYou")
```

When I run this, it shows output as `0` which indicates output is success. But it doesn't add the printer.

If I run this in command prompt:

```
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n \\print-kunnu.com\FollowYou
```

it adds the printer.

Could you please let me know what wrong I am doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import os

source_path = r"\\print-kunnu.com\FollowYou"
os.system("rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n {}".format(source_path))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a path issue. You could try to provide absolute path for rundll32 and the dll.
Another possible issue would be the parsing. If you were running on Linux, I would suggest using shlex but on Windows, I am not sure how it behaves.
Try to catch the exception via:
import os
try:
    os.system("rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /n \print-kunnu.com\FollowYou")
except:
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    print "Error: " + str(exc_type)